# Generate int primary key manually in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

What is the best way to generate a manually int primary key with mysql?

I dont want to use the autoincrement feature.

I taught to create a table with one column of type int named sequence. So every time I'm going to insert a new record first check this column and use the value as the primary key. Then after the insert is successful increment the value of sequence.

Is this a good aproach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a table with one int column of type ***InnoDB***:

```
CREATE TABLE key_table ( next_value INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Then when you want to get a new value for the key you must start a transaction (using the API you are using) and then:

```
SELECT next_value FROM key_table FOR UPDATE
```

Then read the value returned, it is the value for your primary key. Then to increment the value ***while still in the same transaction*** execute:

```
UPDATE key_table SET next_value = next_value + 1;
```

Then commit your transaction.

This will ensure complete consistency *if and only if* you use transaction as described above *and* you use the InnoDB table type.

Comment: As an aside, you can get much better performance if you fetch new keys in bulk. Adapt the above queries to increment by, say, 1000 instead of by 1 each time, then you know that no-one else can ever have the 1000 key values following `next_value`. You then keep a counter in memory and increment it by 1 each time you use a key. When it gets to the original value + 1000 you must fetch another 1000 keys from the database. This is the way that e.g. Hibernate's serial key generator works.

Answer (score 2):

This approach works but you need to have a transaction which wraps these distinct atomic operations (looking up, inserting and incrementing)

However, could you elaborate on why autoincrement column is not good enough? It is safe and guaranteed database feature, so unless you have compelling reasons, I would stick with it.

Comment: Hello.
I don't want to use autoincrement because i think it is not safe enough because after inserting I want to get the current id. For example:
Insert into TABLENAME(id) Values(null);
SELECT last_insert_id() as lastId;

If I use this aproach even if it is on a transaction I dont know what could happen if after the first insert there is another insert with autoincrement but in another table. Then I execute SELECT last_insert_id() as lastId; which will be the value of lastId? the last id from the first table I inserted or the second one?

Comment: I think you need to read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: Agree with Code Duck.

You're worried that LAST_INSERT_ID() will be affected by other insert operations.  However, if you're performing a simple INSERT INTO TABLE; type command, it doesn't matter if other inserts are happening on other connections, as LAST_INSERT_ID() is connection-specific.

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis.

So as long as you're doing simple inserts, just use LAST_INSERT_ID().  An exception would be if you were using stored procedures or some other feature that would cause secondary inserts, but you're probably not.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didnt know last_insert_id() was specific to one connection.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's very reasonable, as long as the value of the next sequence from the given table is delivered via a function or procedure (that itself updates the sequence table) to ensure uniqueness, and not via

```
select max(id) + 1 from ...
```